# How to find the defined name for a specific excel cell in c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm trying to find the defined name of a cell in an Excel file in C#, I tried to find the value and I succeeded in that but I'm not able to find the name.
Here is my code that succeeds in finding the value:

```
            Application application = new Application();
            Workbook workBook = application.Workbooks.Open(requestSheetPath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(sheet);
            Range range = workSheet.UsedRange;
            if (range.Cells[column, row] != null && range.Cells[column, row].Value2 != null)
                return range.Cells[column, row].Value2.ToString();
```

How can I find the defined name?

Comment: Pretty sure you can just use `Range.Name` to test if this cell has a name.

Comment: No such option, I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: `.Range["A1"].Name;` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.name looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Excel.Worksheet.Names

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in wb.Sheets) {
foreach (Excel.Range range in sheet.Names) {
    // this is the named ranges
 }
```

}

you can see [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125947/how-to-get-an-existing-range-name-from-an-excel-worksheet-using-c-sharp-excel-in) for more info